# Ratio of definite integrals

Tags: definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

my school gave this question out and I couldn't think of a way to do it other than bashing by parts multiple times. Is there a clever solution to the question?

Given:

$$ I = \int_{0}^{4\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \, dx $$
$$ J = \int_{0}^{\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \, dx $$

Find the value of $$\frac{I}{J}$$.

(PS: Sorry about the wonky formatting, still trying to work stuff out)

Comment: Try splitting up $I$ at multiples of $\pi$ and translating $x$ so that each subsequent integral is taken over $[0,\pi]$

Comment: I think I get what you mean, so from pi to 2pi, each corresponding point on the function is e^pi of from 0 to pi since the trig part is periodic and then you can do the same for the subsequent domains of x and represent each as a multiple of e^pi and J?

Comment: Precisely, one ends up rewriting $I=(1+a+b+c)J$ for some constants $a,b,c$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let

$$ f(x) = \sin^6 x + \cos^6 x. $$

By using the identities $\sin(x+\pi)=-\sin x$ and $\cos(x+\pi) = -\cos x$, it is easy to check that

$$ f(x+\pi) = f(x). $$

So, we get

\begin{align*}
I
&= \sum_{k=0}^{3} \int_{k\pi}^{(k+1)\pi} e^x f(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{k=0}^{3} \int_{0}^{\pi} e^{x+k\pi} \underbrace{ f(x+k\pi) }_{=f(x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
= \sum_{k=0}^{3} e^{k\pi} J.
\end{align*}

Dividing both sides by $J$, we get

$$ \frac{I}{J} = \sum_{k=0}^{3} e^{k\pi} = \frac{e^{4\pi} - 1}{e^{\pi} - 1}. $$

Answer (score 2):

$$I = \int_{0}^{4\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \,dx$$
$$I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \,dx+\int_{2\pi}^{4\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \,dx$$
Let $y=x-2\pi$,
$$I = \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \,dx+\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{y+2\pi} (\sin^6 (y+2\pi) + \cos^6 (y+2\pi)) \,dy$$
$$I=(1+e^{2\pi})\int_{0}^{2\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \,dx$$
Similarly, let $y=x-\pi$,
$$I=(1+e^{2\pi})\int_{0}^{\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \,dx+(1+e^{2\pi})\int_{\pi}^{2\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \,dx$$
$$I=(1+e^{2\pi})\int_{0}^{\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \,dx+(1+e^{2\pi})\int_{0}^{\pi} e^{y+\pi} (\sin^6 (y+\pi) + \cos^6 (y+\pi)) \,dy$$
$$I=(1+e^{\pi})(1+e^{2\pi})\int_{0}^{\pi} e^x (\sin^6 x + \cos^6 x) \,dx$$
$$I=(1+e^{\pi})(1+e^{2\pi})J$$
Therefore,
$$\boxed{\dfrac{I}{J}=(1+e^{\pi})(1+e^{2\pi})}$$